# changing background Image of button being clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a UIButton which when clicked makes the background image change between OFF and ON images.

I have defined the two images as:

```
let offPosition  = UIImage(named:"Dont Send.pdf")! as UIImage
let onPosition   = UIImage(named:"send Button.pdf")! as UIImage
```

in the view controller I have declared:

```
var smsButtonActive = false
```

the button has an outlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var smsButton: PeControlButton!
```

I have defined the button Click as:

```
@IBAction func smsButtonClick(_ sender: PeControlButton){

  if smsButtonActive {
    smsButton.setBackgroundImage(onPosition, for: .normal)//on position
    appSettings.set(smsButtonActive, forKey: "sendText")//writes status to appSettings
  }else {
    smsButton.setBackgroundImage(offPosition, for: .normal)//off position
    appSettings.set(smsButtonActive, forKey: "sendText")//writes status to appSettings
  }

  smsButtonActive = !smsButtonActive
}
```

My question is that if the switch position starts in the On position it requires a single click to change the image.  If it starts in the Off position I have to double click to get the image to change.  I know its not a major drama as the image changes but I would like to get to the bottom of it if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

When you view load just pass the off image to your button like that way

```
  var smsButtonActive = false. // false means our button image is on off mode 
  smsButton.setBackgroundImage(offPosition, for: .normal)//off position //
```

after that on your button Action we will change the image on below code

```
@IBAction func buttonClick(sender: any){

if smsButtonActive == false{ // when you first click on button then smsButtonActive is false then it goes to if condition where we are setting button on image because our but image by default in off mode and then we are also changing the smsButtonActive value change so when you click another time then smsButtonActive value(which is bool type) get True mode means it will goes to else part where we set the button off image.
 smsButtonActive = true  // here we are setting smsButton type so it will check the else part
  smsButton.setBackgroundImage(onPosition, for: .normal)
  appSettings.set(smsButtonActive, forKey: "sendText")

 }else{

 smsButtonActive = false 
 smsButton.setBackgroundImage(offPosition, for: .normal)//off position
 appSettings.set(smsButtonActive, forKey: "sendText")//writes status to appSettings
 }
```

well may be this will works for you.
Thank you

Comment: Hi Vipin, your code did the trick many thanks. (still trying to work out why it worked) when I have a  bit of time I'll get to the bottom of it thanks again.

Comment: @stako may be you are not getting it so that's why i just place some comments so you can understand. so please read my answer again. Thanks